# How does closing SQLite cursor apply when conn.execute is used in place of named cursor

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor

Is closing a cursor needed when the shortcut conn.execute is used in place of an explicitly named cursor in SQLite?  If so how is this done?  Also, is closing a cursor only need for SELECT, when a recordset is returned, or is it also needed for UPDATE, etc.?

Comment: I'm talking about Python.

Answer (score 0):

The `close()` method allows you to close a cursor object before it is garbage collected.

The connection's `execute()` method is exactly the same as `conn.cursor().execute(...)`, so the return value is the only reference to the temporary cursor object. When you just ignore it, CPython will garbage-collect the object immediately (other Python implementations might work differently).

Comment: Sounds good for CPython.  I'm using standard Python and garbage collection does not always appear to happen immediately.  Any ideas on the need to close a cursor when a recordset is not returned as with UPDATE?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: CPython is the standard Python.